# Is it possible to ask Visual Studio to play a sound after compiling?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

When the project is huge, the cost time for compiling can be several hours? Is it possible to ask Visual Studio to play some sound to alert me the compiling is done.

Answer (score 4):

Add a [custom build step](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h7dhf0ty.aspx) that calls some command line audio player thingy.

Comment: `rundll32 user32,MessageBeep Default` might be usefull.

Comment: @Orient not `blast_it_loud.exe Tchaikovsky1812.mp3`...? ;-.

Comment: @TonyD Clear sinusoid is much more better, due to its spotless mathematical nature.

Answer (score 3):

There is in fact a hidden *windows* setting just for that. Here's an [old link](http://ofekshilon.com/2009/04/16/sound-alerts-on-vs-events/), and here's a current (windows 7) screenshot:

[image]

You get there via Control panel/Sound / sounds tab,  and scroll down to 'Microsoft Visual Studio'.

Comment: You have to restart VS for the changes to take effect.  And I had different settings for each of my installed versions (I am using Express Editions).

Answer (score 2):

Use a [Post Build event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42x5kfw4.aspx).  It will run after the build step.  Attach it to the final executable's project.